# Woocommerce product page 404 not found

Tags: permalinks, woocommerce-offtopic, pages, 404-error, localhost

I don't know what else to try to fix this, i am working on localhost with laragon and i get 404 not found when i go to product link, the url is the same as permalink which i have /%postname%/ and default /product/ in the other hand.

htacccess is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Check your server environment settings and `mod_rewrite` availability. There is nothing to do with WordPress.

Comment: mod_rewrite was active, don't know what caused this but now is working in a new wordpress installation.